# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "onclick", modal box on specific pages

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

What I'm trying is to display a modal box on specific product categories. Everything working, but I get this error from MDN: "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "onclick", btn is null"

Here is my code:

```
//Modal Product Category = Ring

add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'monoscopic_modal', 15);
function monoscopic_modal() {
    global $product;
    ?>
        <?php if( has_term( 'ring', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) : ?> 
            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>

            </div> 
        <?php endif; ?>

            <script>
                // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
                btn.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
                }
            </script>

    <?php
}
```

What's going wrong?
Any help?

Thanks

Comment: the message is clear: your button does not exist when a browser is interpreting this JS code, so it cannot add an event listener to it

Comment: If your `hasTerm` check returns false the button won't render, hence why it returns null

Comment: @KelVarnsen Understand. Did you have a fix for this? I tried this but not working:

if (typeof btn !== 'undefined') {
.
.
.
}

Comment: @loannisKoukotzilas Try null checking it as well (i.e. `if (!btn) {...}`

Comment: @KelVarnsen Thanks a lot. I have posted the answer for anyone who might be interested.

Comment: @loannisKoukotzilas Glad that worked! I realized `document.getElementById` returns null if the element can't be found which is why the undefined check alone doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for anyone who might be interested. Thanks to Kel Varnsen.

Php:

```
<?php //delete it

// Custom HTML inside WC template (with conditional logic)
// Code goes in functions.php

//Modal Product Category = Ring
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'monoscopic_modal', 15);
function monoscopic_modal() {
    global $product;
    ?>
        <?php if( has_term( 'ring', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) : ?> 
            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
}
```

JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

if (!modal || !btn || !span) {
  console.log("Modal is null");
} else {
  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    };

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
  };
}
```